# .NET MVC 4 API Controller not getting AJAX data?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple ajax call that is not sending data correctly. What am I doing wrong? Here is the AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/api/Chat/New',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { id : 10}
        });
```

and here is my controller:

```
 public class ChatController : BaseApiController
    {
        //
        // GET: /Chat/

        [HttpPost]
        public int New(int id = -1)
        {

            return id;
        }
    }
```

`BaseApiController` is my own controller that has  DB context in it and it inherits from ApiController. I cannot get data to send across the wire at all. New() just returns -1 every time.

Comment: Try taking out the dataType: 'json' line. You're not receiving an object in your controller, just a primitive type.

Comment: I have tried that and nothing changed at all

Comment: You said it does hit the controller, just no data? I'm posting an alternative that works for me in this situation

Answer (score 1):

try removing the data type from your ajax call.  Something like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("New", "Chat")',
    type: 'post',
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    data: { id: 10 },
    success: function(result){
        // do something if you want like alert('successful!');
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/api/Chat/New',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ id : 10})
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the answer of the following post
http://forums.asp.net/t/1939759.aspx?Simple+post+to+Web+Api

Basically, Web API Post accept only one parameter, it can be a primitive type or a complex object.

Change your ajax request to the following

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/Chat/New',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { '' : 10}
});
```

Then change your controller as follows

```
[HttpPost]
public int New([FromBody]int id = -1)
{
    return id;
}
```

If it's a complex object like a `ViewModel`, you don't need to use `FromBody`

You can read more about why this is required by reading "Using[FromBody]" section in the following article.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api